# Python - How to count the number of occurrences in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count

For a list like this:

```
spam=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['a',2],['b',2],['c',2],['a',3],['b',3],['c',3]]
```

Need to count the number of occurrences of a, b c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and generator expression -

```
Counter(a for a,_ in spam)
```

Demo -

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> spam=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['a',2],['b',2],['c',2],['a',3],['b',3],['c',3]]
>>> Counter(a for a,_ in spam)
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 3})
```

Comment: Good answer, but in the future I would rather see people who post the code they tried first.

Comment: This can be simplifed a little bit: `Counter(a[0] for a in spam)`

Comment: @VPfB Yes, correct generator expressions may be better in this case. I have updated that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class. Carefull though that it's not summing the values

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
c={}
for i in spam: c[i[0]] = c[i[0]]+1 if i[0] in c else 1
```

Answer (score 0):

cast/convert list to dictionary

```
spam=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['a',2],['b',2],['c',2],['a',3],['b',3],['c',3]]
dict(spam)
```

output: {'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}